# How do I use the raw_window_handle() method from winit rust crate?

Tags: rust, window, vulkan, ash, winit

I'm trying to create my first **Vulkan application** using Rust following [adrien ben's vulkan-tutorial.](https://github.com/adrien-ben/vulkan-tutorial-rs)

As I progressed to [commit 1.2.1](https://github.com/adrien-ben/vulkan-tutorial-rs/commit/e118fd1272d42400c670b95e19f7bd9643b0f933) I noticed he is creating the **winit-window for Windows**.

Because I'm developing the application on my **Linux-system** I decided to leave the pre-scripted path, and try to implement the windowing-part on my own.

So I stumbled across the [ash-window-crate](https://docs.rs/ash-window/0.6.0/ash_window/) which gives me a `create-surface()` method that needs a `window-handle` as a parameter.

***My problem is as follows:***

I'm not able to call the **raw-window-handle function** from my winit-window although the [docs of winit](https://docs.rs/winit/0.25.0/winit/) suggest the Window-Struct implements the **HasRawWindowHandle-Trait**, which to my understanding would expose the aforementioned function.

*I'm trying to create the KHRSurface like this:*

```
let window = WindowBuilder::new().build(&events_loop).unwrap();;
let surface_khr = unsafe { create_surface(&entry, &instance, &window.raw_window_handle(), None).unwrap(); };
```

*and the rust-compiler complains:*

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `RawWindowHandle: HasRawWindowHandle` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:46:70
   |
46 |         let surface_khr = unsafe { create_surface(&entry, &instance, &window.raw_window_handle(), None).unwrap(); };
   |                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `HasRawWindowHandle` is not implemented for `RawWindowHandle`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn HasRawWindowHandle`
```

As I'm quite new to the Rust programming language I'm not very familiar with the **concept of traits** and therefore any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow.

The `window` does indeed implement the `HasRawWindowHandle` trait, and the `create_surface` function wants to be passed a window object that implements this trait.

That tells us that, somewhere inside of `create_surface`, it will call `raw_window_handle` on that object.

But in your code, *you* are already grabbing the `window`'s `raw_window_handle` and passing *that* into the function.

So now `create_surface` would want to get the `raw_window_handle` of your `raw_window_handle.`

Long story short, just try passing in `&window` instead of `&window.raw_window_handle()`.